# Java / Libgdx Kryonet Lagg without too much traffic?

Tags: java, sockets, libgdx, kryonet

Im currently developing a little duengon crawler. And today i tried to implement a local multiplayer mode... When my duengon creates, it also creates some enemys in each rooms, most times in total about 100 enemys. First i did the player part, which looks like so :

```
gameScreen.player.update();

    //Update position
    if(gameScreen.player.networkPosition.x != gameScreen.player.position.x){
        //Send the player's X value
        PacketUpdateX packet = new PacketUpdateX();
        packet.x = gameScreen.player.position.x;
        network.client.sendUDP(packet);

        gameScreen.player.networkPosition.x = gameScreen.player.position.x;

    }
    if(gameScreen.player.networkPosition.y != gameScreen.player.position.y){
        //Send the player's Y value

        PacketUpdateY packet = new PacketUpdateY();
        packet.y = gameScreen.player.position.y;
        network.client.sendUDP(packet);

        gameScreen.player.networkPosition.y = gameScreen.player.position.y;

    }
    if(gameScreen.player.netState != gameScreen.player.state){


        PacketUpdateState packet = new PacketUpdateState();
        packet.state = gameScreen.player.state;
        network.client.sendUDP(packet);

        gameScreen.player.netState = gameScreen.player.state;

    }
```

So it should only send packet updates, when the player changed his position.
Right after that i implemented a joinable player. The connections works and everything is fine until i move the player diagonal. Than the joined player laggs very badly. First i thought thats because my player moves with 200f pixels per second. but also when i do 5 pixels per second it laggs :/ And i dont know why. Heres my player movement code :

```
           if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A) && moveDirections[0]){ 
               position.x -= Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * 200f;       

               state = 1;

           }
           if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D) && moveDirections[1]){
               position.x += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * 200f;    


               state = 2;
               //System.out.println(currentState);
           }
           if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W) && moveDirections[2]){ 
               position.y += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * 200f;           

               state = 3;
               //System.out.println(currentState);
           }
           if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.S) && moveDirections[3]){ 
               position.y -= Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * 200f;

               state = 4;

           }
```

Does anyone got an idea, why it could lag ? Or an idea how to find the issue ? Thats my first time i work with kryonet :/ Thanks for your attention :)

Comment: Anyone got an idea ?